# How to measure WERs of Librispeech using sclite?

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm trying to use sclite as a WER evaluation tool.
Could you give me any advice to use this toolkit for Librispeech?

This is the command line I'm using now (it perfectly works for "wsj")

```
sclite -h $HYPOTHESIS -r $REFERENCE -i <utterance id type> -o pralign -o sum
```

- Format of $HYPOTHESIS and $REFERENCE
  `a b c (utt_id)`
- An example of an utterance id Librispeech

  - 8131-117029-0001

Comment: If you put files in the same format, the same command should work. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: The average WER can be calculated using the command above.
But I can not see the average WER of each speaker since "sclite" can not recognize the format of utterance ids of Librspeech. I wonder if there is a way to specify a custom utterance id format.

Comment: No, you can convert utterance ids instead in post-processing by replacing - with _.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, thanks for the comments. I tried to do the suggested post-processing, but sclite could not recognize utt-id correctly (even with various utterance_id_types such as rm, swd and wsj). However, the value in the "Sum/Avg" row is exactly the same with the score calculating by Kaldi. Thus I will just use as it is unless I really need to know the average WER per speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Ref to sclite src code, https://github.com/foundintranslation/Kaldi/blob/master/tools/sctk-2.4.0/src/sclite/sclite.c

You need to set rfmt and hfmt to be "trn"

Eg: ./sclite -r ~/ref_file trn -h ~/hyp_file trn -i wsj